# Characterization for $ f \in H^2 $ (Hardy space), so that $ \lim_{r \to 1} |f(re^{it})| = 1 $

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Let $f \in H^2$, so $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, $(a_n) \in l^2$ :

Show that

$$ \lim_{r \to 1} |f(re^{it})| = 1 $$ for almost all $t \in [0,2\pi]$

$$\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar a_{n+k}=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    1, & k=0 \\
    0, & k\geq1.
\end{array}
\right.$$

Hint : You may use the theorem (Fatou) : If $f \in H^2$, then it exists $f^*(e^{it})=\lim_{r \to 1} f(re^{it})$ for almost all $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

In both directions I don't see how to even start.

I know that it is:

$ \lim_{r \to 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(re^{it})|^2dt =||f||_{H^2}=||(a_n)||_{l^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2$

Comment: Do integral of $(z^kf) \bar f$ on the unit circle after using that $f$ has radial limit ae (or on circles radius $r$ and let $r$ to $1$

Comment: So I did the calculations like below but I have a problem connecting $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar a_{n+k}=\langle z^kf,f\rangle= \lim_{r \to 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} r^k e^{ikt} \cdot |f(re^{it})|^2dt \\$
and $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{ikt} |{f}^*(e^{it})|^2dt.$ I have seen too little examples of exchanging Limes and Integral. If that is the case here, can you help me on how to argument in our case?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! Let $z \in \mathbb{D} $ (open unit circle) then for some $t \in [0,2\pi]$ and $0\leq r < 1 $ it is
$$z = re^{it}$$
and
$$(z^k f(z))\bar f(z) = (r^k e^{ikt} f(re^{it}))\bar f(re^{it}).$$

Take $r\rightarrow 1$

$(e^{ikt} {f}^* (e^{it}))\bar {f}^* (e^{it})$

Integrate

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (e^{ikt} {f}^* (e^{it}))\bar {f}^* (e^{it})dt$

$= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (e^{ikt} |{f}^* (e^{it}))|^2dt$

$= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{ikt} |\lim_{r \to 1} f(re^{it})|^2dt$

$= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{ikt} (\lim_{r \to 1} |f(re^{it})|)^2dt$

Assuming we want to show $" \Rightarrow "$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{ikt}dt$

$=1, k = 0$ and $0, k\geq 1$

But I don't know the meaning of the Integral I computed
and how I can go on.

I know that $ z^k, k \in \mathbb{N}_0 $ is an ONB of $H^2$
and that for the Fouriercoefficients it is $\langle f,z^k \rangle _{H^2} =a_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Because for $ f,g  \in H^2, f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n, g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n.$

$\langle f,g \rangle_{H^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar b_n$.

Comment: You are almost done since the integral is just $(z^kf,f)$ and the coefficients of $z^kf$ are precisely the shifted coefficients of $f$; conversely the hypothesis implies that $(z^k, |f|^2)=0$ for $k \ne 0$ (conjugation for negative $k$) so absolute value is constant and is $1$ by $k=0$ case

Comment: I just read the comment. Thank you. So I need:

$\langle z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n,z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+k} z^n\rangle_{H^2}
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar a_{n+k}.$

But the calculation you suggested gives us


$\langle z\mapsto f(z)*z^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n+k}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n-k} z^{n},f\rangle_{H^2}$

Which is not the same?

Comment: I am sorry. It is the same! I am studying your comment on the other direction now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the all the help!

$\Rightarrow.$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar a_{n+k}=\langle z\mapsto \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n-k} z^n,z\mapsto \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n z^n\rangle_{H^2}$

$=\langle z\mapsto \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n-k} z^n,z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n\rangle_{H^2}$

$=\langle z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n+k},z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n\rangle_{H^2}$

$=\langle z\mapsto z^k\cdot f(z),z\mapsto f(z)\rangle_{H^2}$

$=\langle (r,t)\mapsto r^ke^{ikt}\cdot f(re^{it}),(r,t)\mapsto f(re^{it})\rangle_{H^2}$

$=\lim\limits_{r\to 1} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi}r^ke^{ikt}f(re^{it})\cdot\bar f(re^{it})\,dt$

$=\lim\limits_{r\to 1} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi}r^ke^{ikt}\cdot|f(re^{it}|^2\,dt$

Here I have used Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. (As I did not see that we could use uniform convergence or the Monotone convergence theorem)

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{ikt}(\lim\limits_{r\to 1}|f(re^{it}|)^2\,dt$

$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{ikt}\,dt$

$=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    1, & k=0 \\
    0, & k\geq1.
\end{array}
\right.$

Now the other direction.

$\Leftarrow.$

$\langle |f|^2, z\mapsto z^k\rangle=\overline{\langle z\mapsto z^k,|f|^2\rangle}$

$=\overline{\langle z\mapsto z^k\cdot f(z), z\mapsto f(z)\rangle}$

$=\overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \bar a_{n+k}}$

$=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    \bar 1, & k=0 \\
    \bar 0, & k\geq1.
\end{array}
\right.$

$=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    1, & k=0 \\
    0, & k\geq1.
\end{array}
\right.$

So we have:

$\Rightarrow z \in \mathbb{D}: |f(z)|^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\langle|f|^2,z\mapsto z^k\rangle z^k$

$=\sum_{n=0}^{0}\langle|f|^2,z\mapsto z^k\rangle z^k$

$=\langle|f|^2,z\mapsto z^0\rangle z^0$

$=1$

Hence we have:

$\Rightarrow |f(z)|=1$

$\Rightarrow |f(re^{it})|=1$

$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{r\to 1}|f(re^{it})|=1$